# windows 7 clock jumps back about every hour + internet disconnects

Tags: windows-7

I have the weirdest problem, for the last few days every hour or so (not exact) the clock jumps about back in jumps of 15 to 60 minutes and after some time the internet disconnects.
i can reconnect the internet by unplugging and plugging back the network cable.

This is the second time this problem happens to me, the first time was when I installed VirtualBox. whaen I removed it the problem was gone.
This time I have no idea what triggered it, the only thing I installed about the time the problem started was iTunes update (10.5.1)
I tried removing it but the problem remained. (also tried to remove other programs i installed day or 2 before and it also didn't help) also, this is not a VM and currently I don't have any VM software.

any ideas..?

UPDATE

since the solution is in the comments i'll write it here - apparently the windows time service got broken, this is the fix: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738995(WS.10).aspx (run "fix it" from IE browser only)

UPDATE 2

The fix didn't work, about 2 hours passed and first the internet disconnected and then the clock jumped back...

This probably means that the problem is not only in the clock

UPDATE 3

A true solution was found, works fine for a day now! The problem was the small battery on the motherboard has run out!, it controls the internal clock. I replaced it with a new one and it's fine since.

Comment: Have you configured ntp-sync? Maybe you're using a wrong time-zone.

Comment: @wullxz what's ntp-sync? the jumps are not accurate, it can jump 20 minutes, and then another 20.. the time zone in the clock settings is correct

Comment: Also, the clock was synced with time server and I disabled it. but the clock acted the same way before and after.

Comment: ntp means "network time protocoll" and it's used to communicate with time-servers to update the local clock. You can check that in your date/time-settings under "Internettime" (or similar... I'm on a german system)

Comment: I know similar behaviour when a machine runs virtually on a VMware ESX server... Is your machine a virtual machine?

Comment: @wullxz this pc is not virtual, but it happened first time when i did install a virtual machine! now i don't have any vm.

Comment: Hey @IlyaD, glad you got the problem figured out! Please put your solution below as an answer and mark it as accepted, so that future visitors can benefit from your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently the small battery on the mother-board, it ran out. I replaced it and it's working fine ever since.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes are:

- misconfigured ntp-settings
- wrong time-zone
- misconfigured time on virtualization-host (e.g.: machine running as vm on VMware ESX)

You could also check your system-log (keystroke: `WINDOWS + R`, type `eventvwr`, open Windows-Logs -> System). Normally the change of system-time should be logged there. 
Do you have log-entries about changing or updating the system-time?

**Update 2011\11\19 21:56**:
Maybe the problem is any third-party-software or another misconfigured service.
Have you already checked your system for malware? You could clean up your installed software, run clean-up-tools like CCleaner and check your autostart (run: msconfig, then disable any not-needed service and application on service- and startup-register).

Comment: this is a notification from when the time jumped back: `The system time has changed to ‎2011‎-‎11‎-‎19T09:27:48.500000000Z from ‎2011‎-‎11‎-‎19T10:27:48.594391300Z.` anything useful?

Comment: and then i'm guessing this one is from the network disconnect: `Name resolution for the name teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.`

Comment: Can you provide Eventlog-ID and -Source of that time-change event? Is there any hint of which application changed the time? The network-event just shows that your dns-server wasn't responding anymore. This is the result of a disconnected network. Maybe it'd help to update your network-drivers.

Comment: this is all the event's output: `- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General 
   [ Guid]  {A68CA8B7-004F-D7B6-A698-07E2DE0F1F5D} 
   EventID 1 
   Version 0 
   Level 4 
   Task 0 
   Opcode 0 
   Keywords 0x8000000000000010 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2011-11-19T11:42:47.500000000Z 
   EventRecordID 335297 
   Correlation 
  - Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  4 
   [ ThreadID]  52 
   Channel System 
   Computer ilya-PC 
  - Security 
   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 
- EventData 
  NewTime 2011-11-19T11:42:47.500000000Z 
  OldTime 2011-11-19T12:29:03.062740000Z 
`

Comment: i looked for `[ ProcessID] 4 [ ThreadID] 52` in the task manger but didn't find

Comment: Try executing commands as described here: http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=1&eventno=10866&source=Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General&phase=1

Comment: You probably watched only at your own processes. This process is surely a system-process and doesn't show up as long as you don't click on "view all users processes".

Comment: The link did help me! I tried manually running the w32time commands but got all kind of errors, googled it and got this fix from microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738995(WS.10).aspx (I used the "fix it" link) from IE

Comment: great, I'm glad I was able to help :) I'd appreciate it if you'd mark my answer as solution (the green check-mark) :)

Comment: sorry, see my second update, i thought it was solved but it isn't.. thanx for the help anyway