# Why does Windows 7 laptop lose internet connection after I change the system time to the future?

Tags: windows-7, networking, date-time

Sometimes when I change the system time on my laptop to the future, then change the time back, I'll lose internet connection with the yellow exclamation point over the internet access systray icon.

After `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` is run, the internet comes back without having to reboot. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows 7 clock jumps back about every hour + internet disconnects](http://superuser.com/questions/359180/windows-7-clock-jumps-back-about-every-hour-internet-disconnects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (probably) because, since you're using DHCP, when you change the system time it confuses DHCP, which uses the date/time to determine your IP lease life/validity.

If you want to avoid it, use a static IP address instead of DHCP.

Comment: This is probably it, are there any commands I can run to reset it back to normal while still using DHCP?

Comment: @ljk Yup, what you have been doing: use ipconfig to Release your current lease, and then request a Renewal (or reboot). :)

Comment: okay thanks for the reply!(couldn't get @[username] to work)

Comment: No problem. you can always shorten it to a single line with the && operators: `ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew`, and/or stick the commands in a batch file on your desktop so you can just double-click it. :)